# jquery closest function not working with addClass

Tags: jquery, class, closest

i have problem with the closest function from jquery.
i want to make a menu where you can click several items.
what i want to know is:
if someone clicked an already selected item in the menu, is there a selected item in front of the just deseleceted item.
i found the closest function which gives back 1 if there is a dom object which matches the selector and 0 if there is non.
so i add the class selected for every clicked menu item and remove it when it gets clicked again.

when you click menu_2, then menu_3, then again menu_3 the closest value should be 1 because there is a selected item in front of the one i just deseleceted.

but this is not the result of my little script, maybe you know something?

regards,
peter

```
   $('li').click(function()
     {
      if ($(this).hasClass('selected'))
      {
       $(this).removeClass('selected');
       alert($(this).closest('.selected').size());
      }
      else
      {
       $(this).addClass('selected');
      }
   });
```

---

```
  .selected
  {
   background-color: red;
  }
```

---

```
<ul>
<li>menu_1</li>
<li>menu_2</li>
<li>menu_3</li>
<li>menu_4</li>
<li>menu_5</li>
</ul>
```

this is my structure:

```
menu_0 <- selected
 menu_0_0
 menu_0_1
 menu_0_2 <- selected
   menu_0_2_0
   menu_0_2_1 <- selected
menu_1
...
```

now i deselect menu_0_2_1 and the function closest should give me the DOM object menu_0_2, because this is the closest object which has the class "selected" as seen in the example above.

Comment: What do you want to accomplish?

Answer (score 1):

You are getting confused by the purpose of [`closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/):

> Get the first **ancestor** element that
>   matches the selector, beginning at the
>   current element and progressing up
>   through the DOM tree.

If you want to get the siblings too, then use [`siblings()`](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/), if you want the immediate next use `next()` ..etc:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('li').click(function() {
        if ($(this).hasClass('selected')) {
            $(this).removeClass('selected');
            alert('Closest: ' + $(this).closest('.selected').length);
            alert('Siblings: ' + $(this).siblings('.selected').length);
        }
        else {
            $(this).addClass('selected');
        }
        return false;
    });
});
```

[Example link](http://jsfiddle.net/ifaour/TnfeN/). The `return false;` is important here to prevent the bubble effect!